# how to substitute with character < in vim?

Tags: vim, command

For example, I would like to substitute character **[** with **<** for the line below:

```
inoremap []     []<Left>
```

my proposed method from command mode in vim is:

```
s/[/\%x3c/g
```

where **\%x3c** is **<** in ASCII hex but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
s/\[/\</g
```

Just escape the characters:

- `[` **must** be escaped to: `\[` (or `[[]`)
- `<` **may** be escaped to: `\<`

Anyway, your problem doesn't seem to be in the `<` but in the `[`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Vim seems strange to me on when to escape and when not. Wonder if there's a list of characters that need to be escape? Didn't seem to happen to such characters like { } ( ) ...

Comment: `<` doesn't need to be escaped, only `[`.

Comment: @root See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions